# nestjs: how import csv datas into mysql database

Tags: mysql, typescript, database, backend, nest

i am searching for a efficient way in NESTjs to import my csv-datas into my mysql database tables.
I cant find sample or tutorials.
Can anyone help me here? Or did i read over the docs of nest belongs to that point?!

Comment: *I cant find sample or tutorials.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: sure, i can prog that issue from the beginning.. thats not why im using a framework like nestjs with many nice packages.. im looking for a community driven package or something like that..

Comment: I think this question could be improved by: listing approaches you have already tried and what you don't like about them; linking resources you have consulted to find an answer and why they weren't sufficient.